# Putting subquery into offset clause

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have table (numbers) with one column:

```
 n
---
 4
 5
67
23
 7
89
```

and I want to get median (only even list of numbers). I thought it would be easy so I wrote:

```
SELECT SUM(ord.n)/2
FROM (
      SELECT n 
      FROM numbers 
      ORDER BY n ASC
      LIMIT 2 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(n)/2-1 FROM numbers)
     ) AS ord
```

but of course it throw me syntax error. I guess I can't insert subquery into offset but I want to know what I have to do to get expected result? I know there are different ways to write query to get median but I need to know is there any possibility to insert 'variable' into offset instead of placing some number?

Comment: Ah forgot to add that I mean a case where we have an even number of numbers ;d

Comment: I guess that both of you mean odd when refer to even and even when refer to odd.

Comment: @beginsql the median of a list with even number of items is the average of the 2 *middle* items (after sorting).

Comment: yes indeed @forpas  i explained it a bit wrong blame it to the leak of caffeine..

Comment: What's the expected result? What version of MySQL are you using? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: Why 45? The median is 15 = (23 + 7) / 2

Comment: Expected result: 15 version: 8.x

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the query below this should work from MySQL version 5.1 and up

```
SELECT 
 AVG(filter.n)
FROM (

SELECT 
   *
 , (@position := @position + 1) AS init_position  
FROM 
 t
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT
      @position := 0
    , @max := (SELECT COUNT(t.n) FROM t)
    , @median_mode := (CASE WHEN ((@max % 2) = 0) THEN 'even' ELSE 'odd' END)
 ) AS init_user_param
ORDER BY 
 t.n ASC

) AS filter
WHERE 
 CASE 
  WHEN @median_mode = 'even' 
  THEN filter.init_position BETWEEN (@max / 2) AND ((@max / 2) + 1)

  WHEN @median_mode = 'odd' 
  THEN filter.init_position = ((@max + 1) / 2)
 END
```

**Result**

```
| AVG(filter.n) |
| ------------- |
| 15            |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/orF5Jybpg1H7NGVTySWwF/0)

**Result when 89 is out the list.**

```
| AVG(filter.n) |
| ------------- |
| 7             |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/orF5Jybpg1H7NGVTySWwF/1)

Comment: *"wow, it's quite a bit long ;p but it works, thanks! "* Yes @beginsql MySQL 8 makes it more easy, just noticed you are using MySQL 8

Comment: There is no need for `@median_mode` and `CASE`. `WHERE filter.init_position BETWEEN @max / 2 AND @max / 2 + 1` [works](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5q9g7AyR64wrdgienYU4FB/0) just fine.

Comment: Yes i agree @PaulSpiegel the `median_mode` user variable and the `CASE END` are pretty much redundant, but on the other hand in my opinion it makes the SQL a bit more easy to follow how and why it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT COUNT(*) counter FROM numbers)
SELECT AVG(n) median
FROM (
  SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by n) ordinal,
    n
  FROM numbers
) t
WHERE (SELECT counter FROM cte) IN (2 * ordinal, 2 * (ordinal - 1))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oaGxZyLU9oH9VjRsJUuPLe/3).
Result:

```
| median |
| ------ |
| 15     |
```

Answer (score 0):

The (probably) most similar solution to your algorithm is to use two queries. First get the offset. Then insert it into your query. The SQL-only way would be to use a prepared statement:

```
set @offset = (SELECT COUNT(n)/2-1 FROM numbers);

set @sql = "
  SELECT SUM(ord.n)/2
  FROM (
        SELECT n 
        FROM numbers 
        ORDER BY n ASC
        LIMIT 2 OFFSET ?
       ) AS ord
";

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt using @offset;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qe1tBrPFAadeLpGvmKnjvc/0)