# How to calculate median value in Cakephp 2.x find

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using bellow function to get median

```
function array_median($array) {
    $iCount = count($array);
    if ($iCount == 0) {
        throw new DomainException('Median of an empty array is undefined');
    }

    $middle_index = floor($iCount / 2);
    sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $median = $array[$middle_index]; // assume an odd # of items

    if ($iCount % 2 == 0) {
        $median = ($median + $array[$middle_index - 1]) / 2;
    }
    return $median;
}
```

but there is any way to calculate median value in Cakephp 2.x find?

Comment: two days ago i answered a MySQL [only method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56826291/2548147) to calculate median on even or odd lists

Comment: @RaymondNijland  Could you please give me query without Odd/even condition? 
I just need median for filed "net_total". Thanks

Comment: Thanks , i got it now